# Datastructure for multi-cast type of message broadcasting

Tags: firebase

We are thinking about migrating from Pusher to Firebase. We are having troubling thinking about how Pusher channels would be represented in Firebase.

In Pusher we have a channel per user. So a user might be in a `user-1` channel, another might be in a `user-2` channel.

Then our backend/server would send a message to both these users via `Pusher.trigger(message, ['user-1', 'user-2'])`.

I think this would usually be done like this:

```
{
    web_page_1: {
        user_1: {
            messages: [{}, {}, ..],
        },
        user_2: {
            messages: [{}, {}, ..],
        },  
        ...
    },

    web_page_2: {
        user_2: {
            messages: [{}, {}, ..],
        },  
        user_3: {
            messages: [{}, {}, ..],
        }
    },
    ....
}
```

Here the problem is: User 1 and User 2 for the same page *might* have a lot of messages in common. Is there a way to reduce this duplication, since these messages can get rather large, sending and storing them per user can get expensive. Also User 1 should not be able to read the messages of User 2.

It would be nice to do something like this:

```
{
    web_page_1: {
        message_1: {
            user_ids: [1,2,3]
            content: {},
        },
        message_2: {
            recipient_ids: [3,4,5]
            content: {},
        }
        ...
    },

    web_page_2: {
        message_1: {
            user_ids: [1,2,3]
            content: {},
        },
        message_2: {
            user_ids: [3,4,5]
            content: {},
        }
    },
    ....
}
```

But then, how would the security policy be applied such that a message can only be read by the user_ids specified in it.

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'll answer later, but did you already have a look at FireChat by any chance? https://github.com/firebase/firechat/blob/master/src/js/firechat.js. Their security rules might be especially interesting: https://github.com/firebase/firechat/blob/master/rules.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If multi-cast is your use-case and the messages get large, I would indeed split the messages from the users and add message-references to the users like you show.

```
Root
    Users
        provider:344923
            Name: Akshay Rawat
            Messages
                1: true
                2: true
                3: true
        provider:209103
            Name: Frank van Puffelen
            Messages
                1: true
    Messages
        1: It's a beautiful day
        2: The sun is shining
        3: I feel good, I feel good
        4: And nothing's gonna stop me now
```

In the above data you can see that you and I are users. The `provider:...` is our uid, but can be anything that allows you to identify the current user. You've received messages 1, 2 and 3, while I have only received message 3. Neither of us has received message 4.

*I took the Web_page level out to simplify things a bit. If you really need that level, you can add it back. The basic approach will remain the same.*

You security rules can then use these message-references to see if the use can read a specific message:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Messages": {
      "$message_id": {
        ".read": "root.child('Users/'+auth.uid+'/Messages').hasChild($message_id)"
      }
  }
}
```

This rule defines the security for any child under messages (identified by `$message_id`). We grant read access if the `$message_id` is references as a message for the current user (`auth.uid`).

Comment: 1. In this example wont a `ref` to `Messages` lead to a permissions denied, since initially there might not be any messages in it.

2. The `User` > `Messages` ref would get the `$message_id` on `child_added` event. However I need to get the `Message` itself. How would that work?

Comment: I think I'll have to do a join like https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html#join. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to get each message with something like `rootRef.child('Messages').child(id).once('value'...` on your handler for `userRef.child('Messages').on('child_added'...`.