# Firebase data structure - is the Firefeed structure relevant?

Tags: firebase

Firefeed is a very nice example of what can be achieved with Firebase - a fully client side Twitter clone. So there is this page : https://firefeed.io/about.html where the logic behind the adopted data structure is explained. It helps a lot to understand Firebase security rules.

By the end of the demo, there is this snippet of code :

```
  var userid = info.id; // info is from the login() call earlier.
  var sparkRef = firebase.child("sparks").push();
  var sparkRefId = sparkRef.name();

  // Add spark to global list.
  sparkRef.set(spark);

  // Add spark ID to user's list of posted sparks.
  var currentUser = firebase.child("users").child(userid);
  currentUser.child("sparks").child(sparkRefId).set(true);

  // Add spark ID to the feed of everyone following this user.
  currentUser.child("followers").once("value", function(list) {
    list.forEach(function(follower) {
      var childRef = firebase.child("users").child(follower.name());
      childRef.child("feed").child(sparkRefId).set(true);
    });
  });
```

It's showing how the writing is done in order to keep the read simple - as stated :

> When we need to display the feed for a particular user, we only need to look in a single place

So I do understand that. But if we take a look at Twitter, we can see that some accounts has several millions followers (most followed is Katy Perry with over 61 millions !). What would happen with this structure and this approach ? Whenever Katy would post a new tweet, it would make 61 millions Write operations. Wouldn't this simply kill the app ? And even more, isn't it consuming a lot of unnecessary space ?

Comment: i have to say its just a demo...

Comment: Sure, that's why I'm asking for a proper way to do this. It will help me understand better how to handle data structure on Firebase...

Comment: I'd rather set the listeners for accounts you follow since there is a limit how many account you can follow but there is no limit to followers. So yes Katy Perry would kill the app. However even setting up 2000 listeners might be not ideal. Perhaps it could rotate let's say 100 accounts at the time...

Comment: Looks better when there is a lot of followers, but for small accounts, several writes are better than non stop listeners over nothing - so as you said, far from ideal. Maybe doing something like this : adding a marker to a dedicated object, watched by a NodeJS on a custom server, that will handle inserting the data by clusters of 100 or 1000... Still, you would occupy a lot of space for duplicate data. I'm realy not sure whether there IS a solution for something like this that would fit as well as a classical relationnal db structure would.

Comment: An alternative would be an approach like discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27422534, which will have better write performance. But that would lead to a transport bottleneck when all Katy's 61M followers are updating their feed in the morning.

Comment: Usefull one. Thanks, it gives me more to think about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With denormalized data, the only way to connect data is to write to every location its read from. So yeah, to publish a tweet to 61 million followers would require 61 million writes.

You wouldn't do this in the browser. The server would listen for `child_added` events for new tweets, and then a cluster of workers would split up the load paginating a subset of followers at a time. You could potentially prioritize online users to get writes first.

With normalized data, you write the tweet once, but pay for the join on reads. If you cache the tweets in feeds to avoid hitting the database for each request, you're back to 61 million writes to redis for every Katy Perry tweet. To push the tweet in real time, you need to write the tweet to a socket for every online follower anyway.