# Designing a Firebase based scalable feed model

Tags: performance, database-design, firebase

**Question :**

How to design a social network "feed" with Firebase as backend, that scales ?

**Possible answers :**

"MVP" solution is to design a `feeds` root child, one for each user, and append any new post from the followed user in every follower's feeds.

```
users
  user1
    name: bob
  user2
    name: alice
    follows: 
      user1: true

posts
  post1
     author: user1
     text: 'Hi there'

feeds
  user2
    post1: true
```

This works well, and is demoed in the `Firefeed` project. But it does not scale well : if Katy Perry wants to post something, her mobile phone will have to write to millions of feed.

Hence the solution reported in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544325/firebase-data-structure-is-the-firefeed-structure-relevant) to delegate this operation to a server based process.

My problem is, Firebase is a "no-backend" solution, and this is the main reason why I use it, so I'd like to make sure there is absolutely no chance of implementing this feature without a server.

What if the `feeds` child is removed in the above schema ?

Then do this :

```
baseRef.child('posts')
       .orderBy('author')
       .whereIn(baseRef.child('users/user2/follows').keys())
```

Unfortunately, `whereIn` does not exists in Firebase API, nor subqueries :(

Any other model structure possible without the need of a server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firebase guys kinda replied on their blog : https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html

The post is about "Data fanning" (spreading items across many nodes in one atomic write operation).

**The technique greatly addresses the feed model of the original question**

The post actually contains example code for implementing it :

- Function for creating the fannout object (actually a simple object with keys being API endpoints to be written)

  ```
  function fanoutPost({ uid, followersSnaphot, post }) {
          // Turn the hash of followers to an array of each id as the string
          var followers = Object.keys(followersSnaphot.val());
          var fanoutObj = {};
          // write to each follower's timeline
          followers.forEach((key) => fanoutObj['/timeline/' + key] = post);
          return fanoutObj;  
  }
  ```
- And the logic using this function :

  ```
  var followersRef = new Firebase('https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/followers');
  var followers = {};
  followersRef.on('value', (snap) => followers = snap.val());
  var btnAddPost = document.getElementById('btnAddPost');
  var txtPostTitle = document.getElementById('txtPostTitle');
  btnAddPost.addEventListener(() => {
        // make post
        var post = { title: txtPostTitle.value };
        // make fanout-object
        var fanoutObj = fanoutPost({ 
            uid: followersRef.getAuth().uid, 
            followers: followers, 
            post: post 
        });
        // Send the object to the Firebase db for fan-out
        rootRef.update(fanoutObj);
  });
  ```

---

*Note: this is way more scalable than a loop writing each time in one follower feed. However, it could nevertheless be insufficient for millions of followers. In that case, it would be safer to trust a server operation making several writes. I think client-side can be used for up to a few hundreds followers, which is the average number of followers on social media. (This needs to be verified by testing though)*

Comment: What about Reading operation here ...... i mean when we fetched all id of post .. then should we call each post's content request again ? for every id we need to call different observer or in loop right ? is this proper or efficient solution ?